# Uploading images in database and Resize the image

Tags: php, image, mysqli

I spend six hours on trying to figure out how to upload images in my database and to re-size images. I new in php so anyone can help me.

I research this post: [How to upload images into MySQL database using PHP code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717506/how-to-upload-images-into-mysql-database-using-php-code)

but I dont know what BLOBS is nor I do not think this post answer my question. I may be wrong so please explain if I am.

Also, I research this Post: [How to add an image to php mysql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23673627/how-to-add-an-image-to-php-mysql-database?lq=1)

::::CHANGES::::

I made changes to my php. I add my variables into my php code and now it not sending images to my server side folder "photo" how can I get that happen?

PHP code:

```
<?php

$filetmp = $_FILES["file_img"]["tmp_name"];
$filename = $_FILES["file_img"]["name"];
$filetype = $_FILES["file_img"]["type"];
$filesize = $_FILES["file_img"]["size"];
$fileinfo = getimagesize($_FILES["file_img"]["tmp_name"]);
$filewidth = $fileinfo[0];
$fileheight = $fileinfo[1];
$filepath = "~warren/mysql2/photo/".$filename;
$filepath_thumb = "~warren/mysql2/photo/thumb/".$filename;
chmod($filepath,0777);
chmod($filepath_thumb,0777);


if(isset($_POST['btn_upload']))
{
    $sPhotoFileName = $filename;
    $nPhotoSize = $filesize;
    $sTempFileName = $filetmp;

if ($sPhotoFileName) // file uploaded
{   $aFileNameParts = explode(".", $sPhotoFileName);
    $sFileExtension = end($aFileNameParts); // part behind last dot
    if ($sFileExtension != "jpg"
        && $sFileExtension != "png"
        && $sFileExtension != "gif")
    {   die ("Choose a JPG for the photo");
    }

    if ($nPhotoSize == 0)
    {   die ("Sorry. The upload of $sPhotoFileName has failed.
Search a photo smaller than 100K, using the button.");
    }
    if ($nPhotoSize > 10240000000)
    {   die ("Sorry.
The file $sPhotoFileName is larger than 100K.
Advice: reduce the photo using a drawing tool.");
    }
    // read photo

    $oTempFile = fopen($sTempFileName, "r");
    $sBinaryPhoto = fread($oTempFile, fileSize($sTempFileName));
    // Try to read image
    $nOldErrorReporting = error_reporting(E_ALL & ~(E_WARNING)); // ingore warnings
    $oSourceImage = imagecreatefromstring($sBinaryPhoto); // try to create image
    error_reporting($nOldErrorReporting);
    if (!$oSourceImage) // error, image is not a valid jpg
    { die ("Sorry.
It was not possible to read photo $sPhotoFileName.
Choose another photo in JPG format.");
    }
}
 $nWidth = imagesx($oSourceImage); // get original source image width
        $nHeight = imagesy($oSourceImage); // and height
        // create small thumbnail
        $nDestinationWidth = 80;
        $nDestinationHeight = 60;
    //$oDestinationImage = imagecreatetruecolor($nDestinationWidth, $nDestinationHeight);
        $oDestinationImage = imagecreate($nDestinationWidth, $nDestinationHeight);
    /*$oResult = imagecopyresampled(
        $oDestinationImage, $oSourceImage,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        $nDestinationWidth, $nDestinationHeight,
        $nWidth, $nHeight); // resize the image
    */
        imagecopyresized($oDestinationImage, $oSourceImage,0, 0, 0, 0,$nDestinationWidth, $nDestinationHeight,$nWidth, $nHeight); // resize the image
        ob_start(); // Start capturing stdout.
        imageJPEG($oDestinationImage); // As though output to browser.
        $sBinaryThumbnail = ob_get_contents(); // the raw jpeg image data.
        ob_end_clean(); // Dump the stdout so it does not screw other output.

    if($_POST['btn_upload'])
    {

    $sBinaryThumbnail = addslashes($sBinaryThumbnail);
    $oDatabase = $link;
    mysql_select_db("upload", $oDatabase);
    $sQuery = "insert into image (thumbnail) values ('$sBinaryThumbnail')";
    echo $sQuery;
    mysql_query($sQuery, $oDatabase);
    }
}

    ?>
```

Here my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="test4.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file_img" />
<input type="submit" name="btn_upload" value="Upload">  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there value in your db ? Or there is problem in both upload and inserting value?

Comment: @niroj adhikary  in my database i got img_id, img_name, img_path, img_type

Comment: your upload paths are incorrrect give path from root . echo __DIR__ (magic constant) to know root path.
It should be like D:\xampp\htdocs\...... (your folder path)
do not use path like $filepath = ".../photo/{$filename}".$filename;
and at last i think you  should not use {$filename}".$filename; after photo/

Comment: @NirojAdhikary I tried it. it still not posted  database. this what i have tried: **$filepath = "http://thing.cs.usm.maine.edu/~warren/mysql2/photo".$filename;
 $filepath_thumb = "http://thing.cs.usm.maine.edu\~warren\mysql2\photo\thumb".$filename;**

Comment: check this link http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Answer (score 2):

PHP CODE:

> > Photo upload, validation at server

```
<?php
$sPhotoFileName = $_FILES['photo']['name']; // get client side file name
if ($sPhotoFileName) // file uploaded
{   $aFileNameParts = explode(".", $sPhotoFileName);
    $sFileExtension = end($aFileNameParts); // part behind last dot
    if ($sFileExtension != "jpg"
        && $sFileExtension != "JPEG"
        && $sFileExtension != "JPG")
    {   die ("Choose a JPG for the photo");
    }
    $nPhotoSize = $_FILES['photo']['size']; // size of uploaded file
    if ($nPhotoSize == 0)
    {   die ("Sorry. The upload of $sPhotoFileName has failed.
Search a photo smaller than 100K, using the button.");
    }
    if ($nPhotoSize > 10240000000)
    {   die ("Sorry.
The file $sPhotoFileName is larger than 100K.
Advice: reduce the photo using a drawing tool.");
    }
    // read photo
    $sTempFileName = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']; // temporary file at server side
    $oTempFile = fopen($sTempFileName, "r");
    $sBinaryPhoto = fread($oTempFile, fileSize($sTempFileName));
    // Try to read image
    $nOldErrorReporting = error_reporting(E_ALL & ~(E_WARNING)); // ingore warnings
    $oSourceImage = imagecreatefromstring($sBinaryPhoto); // try to create image
    error_reporting($nOldErrorReporting);
    if (!$oSourceImage) // error, image is not a valid jpg
    { die ("Sorry.
It was not possible to read photo $sPhotoFileName.
Choose another photo in JPG format.");
    }
}
```

> > Create thumbnail

```
    $nWidth = imagesx($oSourceImage); // get original source image width
        $nHeight = imagesy($oSourceImage); // and height
        // create small thumbnail
        $nDestinationWidth = 80;
        $nDestinationHeight = 60;
    //$oDestinationImage = imagecreatetruecolor($nDestinationWidth, $nDestinationHeight);
        $oDestinationImage = imagecreate($nDestinationWidth, $nDestinationHeight);
    /*$oResult = imagecopyresampled(
        $oDestinationImage, $oSourceImage,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        $nDestinationWidth, $nDestinationHeight,
        $nWidth, $nHeight); // resize the image
    */
        imagecopyresized($oDestinationImage, $oSourceImage,0, 0, 0, 0,$nDestinationWidth, $nDestinationHeight,$nWidth, $nHeight); // resize the image
        ob_start(); // Start capturing stdout.
        imageJPEG($oDestinationImage); // As though output to browser.
        $sBinaryThumbnail = ob_get_contents(); // the raw jpeg image data.
        ob_end_clean(); // Dump the stdout so it does not screw other output.
```

> > Store Thumbnail in database

```
 if($_POST['send'])
    {
    $sBinaryThumbnail = addslashes($sBinaryThumbnail);
    $oDatabase = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "karma");
    mysql_select_db("upload", $oDatabase);
    $sQuery = "insert into image (thumbnail) values ('$sBinaryThumbnail')";
    echo $sQuery;
    mysql_query($sQuery, $oDatabase);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Nice double quote header styling

Comment: @hitarthi panchal do i add my variables into this or do I combine it with my previous php script

Comment: add your variable with this

Comment: @Hitarthipanchal I added the variables and made changes. This is what i got http://thing.cs.usm.maine.edu/~warren/mysql2/test4.php  the file is still not moving to the image folder on the server

Answer (score 0):

As you have image data in $image_p (after resizing), you need to put this variable in your database.

PHP does not provide a way to convert the image object to it's data, so we need to output in buffer and save in variable:

```
ob_start();
$imagecreate($image_p);
$contents =  ob_get_contents(); //this is your image contents
ob_end_clean();
```

Now insert this contents in your database. Make sure the contents column is of BLOB Type.
For example:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Uploadimg (img_id,img_name,img_path,img_type,contents) VALUES ('0','$filename','$filepath','$filetype', '$contents')";
```

---

When you want to show the image in HTML src tag use this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($image_contents_from_db); ?>">
```

Comment: it say it an extra "<" in this code : <img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($image_contents_from_db); ?>" >

Comment: I gave this code as an example. It is HTML code not PHP, use it after closing php tags ?>

Comment: Little tip: use addslashes(ob_get_contents()) instead otherwise you may get a SQL syntax error

Comment: $contents = addslashes(ob_get_contents());